# WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, segmentation-fault

When try working parallel using "threading model".

I run a python file it gives me that error "Python Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

I'm using python 3.6 ,Linux 16.04 and Pycharm 2018

Can someone tell me why this happens and how can I solve?

thanks for helping

["Python Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqCib.png)

Comment: I have a similar error in Pycharm when trying to import matplotlib.pyplot